# When recurring id is generated with format previous_event_id+_R+date

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-apps

Normally, this is the format of a recurring event ID generated by Google:
qmjtng94k5mgge24890nmoasts (26 character alphanumeric)

In some cases, we see that the recurring event ID generated is of the format:
qmjtng94k5mgge24890nmoasts_R20160823T180000

I want to know when this kind of event Id is generated ?
Specifically, when is a recurring event ID generated with the underscore, capital R, date suffix and the same previous eventId prefix?

Comment: You may want to check this [thread](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12201/origin-of-different-styles-of-id-numbers-for-recurring-calendar-events) which explains the origin of different styles of ID numbers for recurring Calendar events. It will differ when you modify or delete an instance. *"Basically, until it gets modified, it'll be the timestamp of the recurrence."* You may also check this [blog](http://icalevents.com/4437-correct-handling-of-uid-recurrence-id-sequence/) for the *"Correct Handling of UID, RECURRENCE-ID, SEQUENCE"*.

Answer (score 5):

When recurring event ID generated with the underscore, capital R and date suffix - it means that you **edited the existing recurrent event** and selected the option "**Following events**" during saving your changes (e.g. changed the title). The "date" suffix means that your changes are applied to all events starting from that date in the existing series.

**Note**: if you changed the recurrent pattern and selected the option "Following events", it will generate the brand-new series with completely unique ID (without underscore, capital R and date suffix).

Comment: for me this poses a serious problem in that the event's original ID I have stored in my DB becomes outdated hence when there's an update to this event I am not able to process this event in my webhook because the ID has changed. Is there a work around for this? What do you suggest?

Comment: I have this exact issue but the event is on an service account that no one has access to... did you ever see if the event id was also changed by google?